# Spring Test - Mock @ModelAttribute

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I have a `RestController` that I'm attempting to test via Spring MVC Test.  It has the following `ModelAttribute` in it:

```
    @ModelAttribute("authUser")
    public User authUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal SpringAuthUser springAuthUser) throws Exception {
        User user = ConstantsHome.userprofileMgr.getUserByUserId(springAuthUser.getUsername(), true, true);
        user.updateRights(null);
        request.getSession().setAttribute(ConstantsHome.USEROBJECT_KEY, user);
        return user;
    }
```

When I run a test against this `RestController`, I'm getting a `NullPointerException` inside this `authUser` method.

Is there a way to mock this method such that the mocked method gets used instead of this one for testing?  I've read other posts on this and thought I could just pass an "authUser" param in my test but that's not working.  Ultimately trying to make this "authUser" not throw an NPE...here is my test...

```
    @Test
    public void testGetAllUsers() throws Exception {
        String userJson = AvadaObjectMapper.getMapper().writeValueAsString(new User());
        System.out.println("userJson=" + userJson);
        MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/").param("authUser", userJson).accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andReturn();

        String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();

        assertTrue(content.contains("Hello"));
    }
```

Comment: I don't know what `ConstantsHome.userprofileMgr` is, but it should probably instead be an `@Autowired` field within the class that you can then inject a mock into and stub the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get my `authUser` to work via the test configuration class below.  Pay attention to the `.defaultRequest...` line in particular as that is where the auth user gets established.  I use the class below as the `@ContextConfiguration` class on all of my tests.

```
import com.avada.rest.api.users.UserService;
import com.avada.rest.api.users.TestUserService;
import com.avada.rest.security.SpringAuthUser;

import java.util.HashSet;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors;
import org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters={
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=UserService.class)
              })
public class TestSpringRestConfig {

    public static final SpringAuthUser AUTH_USER =
        new SpringAuthUser("test", "test",
            new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>() {{
                add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
            }}
        );

    @Bean
    public UserService userService() {
        return new TestUserService();
    }

    @Bean
    public MockMvc mockMvc(WebApplicationContext wac) {
          return MockMvcBuilders
                 .webAppContextSetup(wac)
                 .defaultRequest(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/").with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user(AUTH_USER)))
                 .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
                 .build();
    }
}
```